# Change datepicker format from mmddyyyy to ddmmyyyy

Tags: date, datepicker, date-formatting, ipywidgets

I am using the datepicker widget from ipywidgets in a project that I am making in Jupyter Lab. My computer is set up as english but i live in Denmark.
When I use datepicker the standard format is mmddyyyy (maybe because my computer is set up as english) and I would like to change this to ddmmyyyy.

Thank you.